# Writepermission to external SDCard in Lollipop without OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: uri, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdcard

I read about the ability for apps to ask the user to choose a folder to write data with new intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE in Lollipop.
This I understood.

My Question: Is this the only way to get writepermission to an external storage (SD-Card) for an app by letting the user choose a directory with the OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Dialog, or are there other ways with the new Lollipop ?

I mean I would like to write directly onto the external storage without asking the user. Or would it be possible to simply ask for the permission to write to external sdcard ? (Not all Users are familiar with folders and so on.... )

Any hints ?